# Form designer only shows the form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, windows-forms-designer

I was working at the forms designer and yesterday the designer literally only showed the form. Tried copying the .designer.vb to another new form and the same thing happened. Also when built it just shows what the designer shows. Compare the two versions: 
(Had to use pastebin as the code is too long for a post, and it rejects my post if more than two links are used.)

Current code: [pastebin.com/SsgR7YWD](http://pastebin.com/SsgR7YWD)
Current form view:
[image: Screenshot: Only showing the form...]

Previous code: [pastebin.com/bXCL3jhH](http://pastebin.com/bXCL3jhH)
Previous screenshot:
[image: Screenshot: The previous version.]

Why it is not showing the controls? I know it is a long piece of designer code but I can't find where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run your code through [this site](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) that compares to blocks of text and shows the differences - there's a lot - you might want to do the same and have a look at the differences. It may be easier to delete the form and start again to be honest. Having said that, you might be able to spot what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You should just delete the form and start again. A few tips to having a better UI ---
Use layout grids for the button-checkboxes and let the buttons occupy the whole horizontal space.

And remember to backup your code often so that things like this won't happen again - use something like GitHub and commit your files whenever your day is finished.

Happy coding!